# Utilizar propriedade de um objeto ao declara-lo em javascript

Tags: javascript, objetos

Pessoal estou iniciando no javascript e tenho muitas duvidas relacionadas a objetos. Umas delas é a seguinte: Vamos supor que eu crie um objeto.

Aqui eu tenho uma lista e desejo guarda-la dentro de um objeto e uma função deste objeto serve para alterar a cor desta lista.

(Não é exatamente isso que desejo fazer mas da pra entender)

```js
var Objeto = { 
        //Aqui eu guardarei meu elemento.
  lista : document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
        //E esta funcao server para alterar o style das LIs.
  alt_cor : function(){
   Objeto.lista.setAttribute("style", "color:red");
    }
   }
   Objeto.alt_cor();
```

```html
<ul class="lista_frutas">
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Laranja</li>
  <li>Maça</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tens de mudar, ou ter em conta, 2 coisas no teu código para ele funcionar:

- dentro desse objeto as funções vão correr no contexto dele próprio. Isso quer dizer que podes usar `this` para aceder ao Objeto.
- `.getElementsByTagName()` dá-te uma lista de elementos. Para usares `. setAttribute()` tens de usar num elemento, e não numa lista de elementos. Assim tens de iterar (percorrer) esses elementos e usar o `.setAttribute()` um a um.

```js
var Objeto = {
  lista: document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
  alt_cor: function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.lista.length; i++) {
      this.lista[i].setAttribute("style", "color: red;");
    }
  }
}
Objeto.alt_cor();
```

```html
<ul class="lista_frutas">
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Laranja</li>
  <li>Maça</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Legal a resposta mas, deixa acrescentar algo. E se eu remove-se o for 
 e fora do objeto acrescenta-se um setInterval() para executar esta função a cada 1 segundo, e assim  as cores das LIs se alterarem automaticamente num certo intervalo; como ficaria o script?

Comment: @WendelGomes Queres chamar alt_cor mudando um a um? ou trocar todos a cada vez que o setInterval executa? Explica qual a duvida que tens para poder explicar melhor.

Comment: Isso alterar um a um.

Comment: Isso com a mesma estrutura do objeto só que ao invés de usar o for para todos sera alterados rapidamente, utilizar o setInterval() para altera-los um a um.

Comment: @WendelGomes => https://jsfiddle.net/md9txce5/ (escrevi mais umas linhas para ficar mais interessante :) )

Comment: kkkkk Bacana o esquema que você criou. Eu tinha feito aqui só que a forma que você fez ficou muito melhor. Usei uma função fora do objeto para executar a função que estava dentro não consegui executar de dentro do objeto. Muito Obrigado me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 1):

Seu código ficaria como abaixo.

Você cria o objeto e decalara sseu método dentro dele que recebe como paramentro qual elemento deseja mudar.

Depois fora do objeto você chama o método e passa qual objeto da lista deseja mudar de cor pelo seu index.

Existem mil maneiras de fazer isso mas estou dando um exemplo bem simples e didatico para você entender como funciona uma lista e declaração de métodos.

```js
var objeto = {
 lista: document.getElementsByTagName('li'),
 alt_cor: function(elemento) {
  elemento.setAttribute("style", "color:red");
 }
};

objeto.alt_cor(objeto.lista[0]);
objeto.alt_cor(objeto.lista[1]);
objeto.alt_cor(objeto.lista[2]);
```

```html
<ul class="lista_frutas">
  <li>Banana</li>
  <li>Laranja</li>
  <li>Maça</li>
</ul>
```